# Bootstrap dropdown-menu - full width and central horizontal items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navbar below has a dropdown-menu which displays a horizontal list of `<li>` elements

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

How can I ensure that the dropdown-menu acts the same was as the div container class? ie: full width of the screen with the items centralised?

```
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-left" href="/home/"><span class="logo"></span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="">
          <a href="/opt1/">Option 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/opt2/">Option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/opt3/">Option 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More...<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop1/">Dropdown 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop2r/">Dropdown 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop3/">Dropdown 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop4/">Dropdown 4</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/6t128bbk), is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Yamm Menu for Bootstrap](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/) , this is what you will need.

Comment: I don't want to use another plugin or menu framework, just amend the CSS to obtain my desired result